# How to use less @variable for SVG inline style "stop-color"

Tags: css, svg, less, gradient, linear-gradients

I have two variables for colors in color.less

```
@color-example-1: red;
@color-example-2: yellow;
```

and an svg in example.html that looks something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="24" x2="48" y2="24">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFF33B"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E93E3A"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle class="st0" cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to either replace the stop-color value with a @variable or (even better) define the whole linearGradient in the css file?

A desired result would be something like this:

css

```
.example-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, @color-example-1 0%,@color-example-2 100%);
}
```

html

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <circle class="example-gradient" cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't define the whole gradient in CSS.  CSS gradients don't currently work on SVG elements.  They might one day in the future.  If they did, you would use something like the following:

```
circle {
  fill: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, orange)
}
```

However all is not lost. You definitely can restyle the `<stop>` elements in the SVG gradient definition.

Note that the `style="stop-color: ..."` in the SVG gradient will override any CSS you define.  So the first thing you need to do is remove it, or change it to a presentation attribute (`stop-color="#abcdef"`).

```css
.stop1 {
  stop-color: blue;
}

.stop2 {
  stop-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
  </style>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="24" x2="48" y2="24">
    <stop  offset="0" class="stop1" stop-color="#FFF33B"/>
    <stop  offset="1" class="stop2" stop-color="#E93E3A"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle class="st0" cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
</svg>
```

Note that I obviously haven't used LESS here, but it should work fine as long as your SVG is inlined in your HTML.